# How to add a Firebase new doc with multiple keys and value through loop in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got this code in JS and I loop through all the elements with a specific class and then I want to take the id of each element and set that as a key with the value of each element to Firestore database.

Instead of doing something like this:

```
db.collection('fixprices').add({
    name: htmlname.value,
    stmp: gettime,
    fix1: value,
    fix2: value,
    fix3: value,
    fix4: value,
    fix5: value,
    fix6: value,
    fix7: value
});
```

Can I do it through the loop taking each element id and replace it with the fix1,fix2... and for the value also?

Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: If you have multiple data stored in somewhere you can do it. But you have to keep on changing the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
const elements = [
    { id: 'id1', value: 'some value' },
    { id: 'id2', value: 'some other value' },
    { id: 'id3', value: 'another value' },
];
const objectToAdd = {
  name: htmlname.value,
  stmp: gettime
};
elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    objectToAdd['fix' + (index + 1)] = element.value;
});
db.collection('fixprices').add(objectToAdd);
```